# Solve the recurrence $a_n=na_{n−1}+n!$

Tags: recurrence-relations

I'm working on a practice set:

Solve the recurrence $a_n=na_{n−1}+n!$ for $n>0$  with $a_0=1$ 
Give a simple expression for $a_n$

For this problem I know the answer is $(n+1)!$
But I'm not sure how to get there....

Here is what I did so far:

I divided the equation by n so:
$\frac{a_n}{n} = a_{n-1} + (n-1)!$

Then I used telescoping, so:
$\frac{a_n}{n} = a_{n-1} + (n-1)!$

$\frac{a_{n-1}}{n-1} = a_{n-2} + (n-2)!$

$\frac{a_{n-2}}{n-2} = a_{n-3} + (n-3)!$

$...$

So I cancel terms across the equal sign and I get:

$a_n = a_0 + (n-1)!$

But this is not correct.

Thanks for help

Comment: Did you try proving it by induction?

Comment: I haven't.... the assignment was on telescoping so was trying to first solve it that way - but open to any info if you sense you can use induction:)

Comment: If you edit in your telescoping argument, we may identify the mistake.

Comment: Hi! Thanks so much @J.G. I added my incorrect telescoping process

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Telescope $b_n:=a_n/n!$, which satisfies $b_n-b_{n-1}=1$ because$$b_n=\frac{na_{n-1}+n!}{n!}=\frac{a_{n-1}}{(n-1)!}+1=b_{n-1}+1.$$

Comment: +1; this works well, and I think it's what OP was looking for

Comment: @J.G. would like to understand a bit more about your process. I'm not sure I understand $b_n := a_n/n!$ curious how you got there - thanks!

Comment: @KatieMelosto I divide by something that multiplies by $n$ at each step, because you need to telescope something of the form $b_n-b_{n-1}$. Your mistake was in trying to telescope something that isn't of that form.

Comment: @J.G.Thanks so much! When you divide $b_n := a_n/n!$ is that: $(a_n = na_{n-1} + n!)/n!$? Trying to put the math together

Comment: @KatieMelosto See edit.

Answer (score 1):

Induction works:

base case:  $n=0$

induction step:  $a_{n+1}=(n+1)a_n+(n+1)!=(n+1)(n+1)!+(n+1)!=(n+2)!$